# Changing the background color and text color of the navbar for every page in a website

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have created a landing page which has a black background for the navbar and has text in white color but I want to have a white background for the navbar with its text in black for the rest of the pages in a website.

Can anyone suggest how I can change the color for the remaining pages?

I've read that jQuery can help out in such a case but I have no experience with jQuery.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
      <header>
        <nav>
          <div class="menu-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="page1.html">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
          </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>
    </header>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 60px;
    animation: left-in 0.5s ease-in forwards;
    animation-delay: 0%;
    opacity: 0;
}
nav ul {
    line-height: 15px;
    list-style: none;
    background: black;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 40px;
    transition: 1s;
}
nav.black ul {
    background: white
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 16px 20px;;
}
nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}
a:hover {
    color: orange;
}
.menu-icon {
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    text-align: right;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 15px 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
}
@keyframes fade-in
{
    from
    {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to
    {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@keyframes left-in
{
    from
    {
        transform: translateX(-200px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to
    {
        transform: translateX(0px);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I for sure don't recommend the previous two answers as it is not preferrable to make two `css` files, and for sure in the `SEO` point of view inlining the style is **not recommended**

I suggest you add a class to the **BODY** tag that is only added for inside pages change your code to something like this:

```
<style>
    nav {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        line-height: 60px;
        animation: left-in 0.5s ease-in forwards;
        animation-delay: 0%;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    nav ul {
        line-height: 15px;
        list-style: none;
        background: black;
        overflow: hidden;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: right;
        margin: 0;
        padding-right: 40px;
        transition: 1s;
    }
    .inside nav ul {
        color: #000000;
        background: #fff;
    }
    nav ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 16px 20px;;
    }
    nav ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    }
    a:hover {
        color: orange;
    }
    .menu-icon {
        line-height: 30px;
        width: 100%;
        background: black;
        text-align: right;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 15px 24px;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #fff;
        display: none;
    }
    @keyframes fade-in {
        from {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        to {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
    @keyframes left-in {
        from {
            transform: translateX(-200px);
            opacity: 0;
        }
        to {
            transform: translateX(0px);
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
</style>

<body class="inside"> <!-- or replace it with (home) for your homepage or no class needed for homepage -->
<div class="wrapper">
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="menu-icon">
                <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="page1.html">About Me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page2.html">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page3.html">Publications</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your opinion on my answer. However, I have to disagree. First of all, I would be extremely interested (as a full-time web dev) to read and learn more about the impact of inlining a `background` property for a `nav`; could you provide one or perhaps two reputable articles explaining that? Secondly, OP mentioned that she had one (1) page that was an exception to her CSS stylesheet/rules, and contrary to your statement, *it is* common practice to use inline CSS for such a case of a unique exception moreover for two properties only. Lastly, there are 2 answers, not 3.

Comment: Thank you so much for solving my query. I was looking for something like this as creating separate CSS files for each page wouldn't have been a good idea as you suggested.

Comment: @LaurentC, you can find some article are discussing about that but sorry I'm on my mobile and can't search but here is an article talking about that, anyway it is not a major issue to do so, but on the other hand it is not a flexible solution to do that, regardless of if it is one page or thousand!! you are using CSS files why not using it proper way and take advantage of it.. lets say in the future he wanted to add `::before` this is impossible to do using online style so he will try to find a way to do so, why not do it right from the first time!!

Comment: @LaurentC there was a comment added and seems to be deleted that suggested to add different `css` files, that's why I mentioned this point.

Comment: @LaurentC http://www.promptwebsolution.com/blogs/why-is-inline-css-harmful-for-seo

Comment: I work in SEO, and it is not accurate to say that "inlining the style is not recommended" for SEO. It could *potentially* have a impact on SEO if it bloats the page to such an extent that it slows down the page load, and if that is the case you have more problems with your code than SEO! Or it *potentially* could reduce the size of a one-use CSS rule if you want to think if it in those terms only. Even the article you link to says (in 2 separate places) that "***Inline CSS is not harmful***" but can cause some minor problems for SEO, so please don't include misinformation in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use the CSS stylesheet that you are using (CSS in the HTML code); and for that specific page (landing page) you only have to inline it in the HTML element and it will override the CSS.

Like this:

CSS code for all pages

```
.nav {background:white;color:#000000;}
```

inline CSS code only on the landing page

```
<nav style="background:black;color:#FFFFFF;">
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment sir. I will be trying out your suggestion as well and will let you know if it works to solve my query.

Comment: Yes, it solves it entirely. Both answers are perfectly valid and equivalent. And just so that you are not mislead in thinking that inlining one or two properties here and there on the fly has an impact on the SEO or on anything and is very bad - it is not -, please refer to these interesting expert articles. This whole discussion highlights the importance of *proper research* when answering a question on a Q&A forum like SO. Thank you.

Comment: #1 https://www.lostsaloon.com/technology/why-is-inline-css-bad-is-it-really-that-bad/ (See at the end, answer="No"). #2 https://www.quora.com/Why-is-an-inline-CSS-harmful-for-SEO#:~:text=Yes%2C%20it%20does.,load%20time%20too%20will%20reduce. (They mention an *eventual* impact if *too much* inline is used, yes of course as it would impact the page load speed adn thus PSI score. But inline one line of CSS? Absolutely not a single bit of impact on SEO. // What I realy couldn't find was a single article explaining a negative impact of some inlining (on a small website such as this one). Thank you.

Comment: Your suggestion works as well and solves the problem I was facing. I am new to this field of CSS and will read the links you have suggested to learn and improve my knowledge regarding this topic. Thank you for taking out your time and providing me with your valuable advice.